# Js how to map through different Json data types

Tags: javascript, json, mapping, fetch-api

I'm using fetch api in javascript. However, I'm having trouble mapping through different JSON object formats. Here are two snippets of my code, the first one working the second one doesn't because of the JSON format.

**This works great --**

```
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=3')  

    .then(results => { return results.json(); })   

    .then(function(data) {                         

    {data.results.map((key) => console.log(key.gender))}

    });
```

**This Doesn't work -- because the JSON format id different**

```
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')  

       .then(results => { return results.json(); })   

       .then(function(data) {                          

       {data.results.map((key) => console.log(key.gender))}

    });
```

**This is the error I get**

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at

Can someone explain how I can map through different json format types 
THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: second fetch request result is object and no property of gender key... so play result based on result data structure....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `results` property in this dataset, and it's only one "result":
`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`

There's no reason to map a single item, if you use this dataset, though:
`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/`

You can map it, but still, there's no `result` property in the dataset, nor `gender` property on the items... so you'd need to map the `data` object and and an existing property... i.e. `website`:

```
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')  

       .then(results => { return results.json(); })   

       .then(function(data) {                          

       {data.map((key) => console.log(key.website))}

    });
```

Comment: Thanks very much it makes perfect sense now. In situations where I only fetch one result as shown in my code, how should the code be handled if not looped/mapped? Should it just be extracted as a single property and stored in a variable or if in react a state

Comment: What I do when results are sometimes either singular or an array, is just check if the result is an array or an object, and simply wrap it in an array.  Not perfect, but it's a quick solve.

Comment: Cool thanks :) are there any benefits of wrapping the results by an array? can they just be left as objects or will this interrupt the mapping function

Comment: `map` only works with arrays, not specifically but usually arrays made of objects. wrapping a single object in array just means you can pass it through the same mapping process without having to build another flow for individual results